# Angular - Is a multiple used Component completely created itself?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a little question about Angular Components.

I often read that you should use components only to display data and interact with the user, and for your "business logic" you should prefer services.

So my question is the following (just an example):

Let's say I have made a component to upload files via drag and drop. I have the logic to get the data from the drag and drop and store it in an array (and maybe much more other functions) inside that components typescript file.

Now when I am including this component twice inside one parent component (because  I need two upload fields for example), are both referencing to the same or is also the program logic inside that component created twice for each instance?

If so, then I should try to keep as much shared program logic as possible in singleton services so they are only created once at runtime and not wasting memory etc., shouldn't I?

Hope somebody understands what I am meaning :).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you add the component twice into your parent, then two different instances will be created (each owning unique scope).

You should however abstract upload/handling logic into a service. Provide that service in module to make it a singleton. If you want instance per component, then provide it inside component.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: When the same component is added twice, then everyhting will exists twice (all functions, fields, properties inside the model)? So it is better to include any logic that is shared between all components like reading the dropped files and validate them (correct filetype etc.) into a singleton service so this exists only once?

Comment: @Sazeidya, yes all methods, properties and model will exist twice. It's like if you called a constructor twice with 'new'. Treat your singleton as a single source of logic (that is easy to debug!).

Comment: Thanks for your time. It helped me a lot understanding this better :)

Comment: @Sazeidya, my pleasure :). Also, you can think of services like if they were "prototypes". Single occurance (unless injected per component), stores reusable and generic methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you create two components in your template which are similar for example:

```
<app cumstom></app custom>
<app cumstom></app custom>
```

This will result in two objects being created who both have their own model (data) and view. They don't know anything of each other.

If you want them to communicate it is often smart to use a service which you can inject into both components so they can share the same data. If a service is provided in your `ngmodule` is will only be created once (so it is a singleton).

Answer (score 0):

Well I think what you need is a smart component, where you can put your boths uploads-component and inject your service logic in this smart component. The smart component will be responsible to provide the bridge of the common logic between the two components.